# Import from index only works in DEV, not in production

Tags: reactjs, import, webpack, es6-modules

For some reason the way I'm importing my components only works in DEV mode. In production I get an error.

I have a main component that imports 2 components in the directory via an `index.js` that exports all components in that dir.

This is my folder structure:

```
|- index.js
|- Component.js
|- ComponentEmpty.js
|- ComponentFull.js
```

index.js

```
export default from './Component';
export { default as ComponentEmpty } from './ComponentEmpty';
export { default as ComponentFull } from './ComponentFull';
```

Component.js

```
import { ComponentEmpty, ComponentFull } from './';

...

return (
    <div>
        {
            (!content.length)
                ? <ComponentEmpty 
                    content={content}
                />
                : <ComponentFull />
        }
    </div>
);
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

Which doesn't happen if import this way:

```
import ComponentEmpty from './ComponentEmpty';
import ComponentFull from './ComponentFull';
```

Any clues?

Comment: Can you add your webpack config? the answer typically lies therein :)

Comment: @cbll you're right, I'll try to reproduce it in the Starter project I got from: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/webpack.config.prod.js